# How to organize entities in an ECS model?

Tags: c++, entity, game-engine, entity-component-system

I have a render system that iterates over all MeshDrawData components and batch and draw them. My ECS implementation only allows one type of component per entity.

Now I want to represent the "Player" pong paddle. My OOP mindset says this:

```
Pseudocode:
auto e = createEntity();
createSpriteComponent(e,...); // this creates a MeshDrawData internally for e entity.
createColliderComponent(e,...);
```

This works ok, BUT let's say that now I want to render a line too.
If I make this:

```
Pseudocode:
auto e = createEntity();
createSpriteComponent(e,...); // this creates a MeshDrawData internally for the e entity.
createColliderComponent(e,...);
createLineComponent(e,...); // this creates a MeshDrawData internally for the e entity
```

Here you can see the problem.. I created two MeshDrawData components for the entity e..

Given my unreal engine background, I create an actor and add components to it. I always thought that in ECS an entity is similar to an actor but I see that I'm completely wrong.

How do you organize your entities to for example allow use cases like the one I mentioned before? What an entity should represent exactly?

Possible solutions:

1. Never create an entity with an SpriteComponent and a LineComponent that create the same MeshDrawData in the same entity.. (obvious but error-prone)
2. Create a child entity for each SpriteComponent and/or LineComponent and add those to the respective child. This would work but it will make long entity hierarchy trees.. not sure if it's more error prone.
   ...

Answer (score 1):

`1:1 Entity:Component` is a boring limitation, but also a good restriction of most ECS engine.

To fix the issues, I generally do one of these :-

1. **Forbid it by default** :: The game engine will throw assert-fail in your second case.
2. **Add checking** e.g. in `createLineComponent` whether `MeshDrawData` already exists, and do some custom things.

   Mostly I do it like :-

   ```
   void createLineComponent(Entity e){
       auto meshComponent=engine->addJustInCase<MeshDrawData>(e);
       //^ if the component exists - just request the component, if not, create it
       meshComponent->setFormat ...
   }
   ```
3. **Split the entity** and **add a One-To-Many relation** :: Suitable for over-complex entity.

   3.1 **Keep it simple** - parent cache child entity(s) as its field(s).

   3.2 **Full system** for a certain 1:N relation.
        The child relation system should be very ***specific*** in type,
   e.g. `1:N Collider-Sprite`, not `1:N entity-entity`.

In my game, I mix them about 60:30:10(9:1). It works well.
If it starts to become a mess - use the factory pattern to encapsulate it.

<sub>If anyone has any (better) ideas, please answer.  I would like to hear it too.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now I'm doing your 2) approach. I overwrite the MeshDrawData with the latest component added that needs it. I will not select this as the correct answer, to see if anyone has another idea.

Comment: @FrameBuffer Nice. If you find anything useful or finish your game with this approach, please let me know.  :)

Comment: I was thinking about it more abd my conclusion is that you can decide to put all your state in the ecs or share it with systems. My approach is now to put ALL the state in components, just to be consistent. Given that i decided to create an child for each diferent "renderer component" that the entity have. And in the "renderer components" of the entity save a reference to the entity in case you have to acces it.

Comment: @FrameBuffer  Just to check my understanding.  Do you ... (1) allow 1 entity to have > 1 `renderer component` by enhancing your ECS core engine?   Or  (2)  diminish/reduce `renderer component` to not be a ECS component any more, and manage it manually instead?  Or something else? ... I did (2) only once. It is in a performance-critical area of my Physics Engine (`manifold component`).

Comment: I have "only one component per type in an entity". What I changed from an architecture standpoint is that an entity with a LineRenderer and a SpriteRenderer doesn't make sense for me so I ended doing your first (1) approach (because it's something wrong).

For example, an Sprite is an entity that has a Transform and a Sprite (that will create and handle their own MeshDrawData). So a character that has an sprite will be represented by an entity (the player) with a child entity (the sprite).
If the player wants to draw a line,the Line is another entity (transform, LineRenderer->MeshDrawData)